# Changes in the vue file not applying in the browser

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I am working in project having technology(laravel + vuejs).In that there is a form created in vue file and i want to add a text in the vue file.So as i have seen that "when any changes is done in vue file then need to rebuild the application".And i see that there are commands for rebuild the application is `npm run dev` , `npm run prod` , `npm run watch` and `npm run watch-poll`. I have tried all this commands after saving the file through `FTP` but sometimes the changes is applied **(Note : Not immediately but after some duration)** and sometimes no changes apply in the browser.When i tried the above command by executing it then there is no such error occurs and the rebuild is done successfully.So what will be the issue can you please suggest something that i need to configure?

Below is the code of `package.json`,`webpack.mix.js` file and after that i have attached image of putty in which application rebuild is done.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: did you uploaded `app.js` to server by ftp?

Comment: no.Its is there by default when laravel is installed.

Comment: you need upload its after  build vue files

Comment: What i need to upload?Can you please explain in detail what you are trying to say.I am new to vuejs so its helpul if you explain in brief.

Comment: you need to upload `app.js` file to server

Comment: Its already there on server.And whatever changes i have done in the vue file they are link with app.js file

Comment: Are you doing this in your local environment or on your server?

Comment: Doing on the server.

Answer (score 6):

I think you are not understanding what npm run dev/prod/watch do. If you alter the .vue file in your resources folder, then have npm rebuild your assets, then ftp the vue file to your server, nothing should happen.

Depending on how you have your laravel mix file set-up, the file you need to ftp to the server is likely public/js/app.js.

You should really consider getting your local environment setup for development, there is nothing I can image worse than viewing your changes by ftp-ing files to a server.

Comment: Can you tell me what steps to do so that i can get the result as i mention the issue in my question.As i am beginner in Vuejs i am not getting what to do?

Comment: Please update your question with your webpack.mix.js file located in your project's root folder.

Comment: Kurt Friars have you checked my question?As you had told i updated my question with the code of webpack.mix.js file.Please let me know with the answer so that i can implement it and resolve my issue.

Comment: @SohilChamadia You need to add much more detail. ie. The vue file, where it is being included in blade, relevant parts of app.js, etc..

Comment: @SohilChamadia To be honest, you really just need to read some documentation and tutorials. Can start with, https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/mix

Comment: Kurt Friars thank you for your suggestion.But i thought you will understood my question carefully.Any way thank you for giving your precious time to answer my question.